# React Native useContext Error: Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-context

I am setting up the framework for user authentication on a new React Native project to work out the bugs. I have 2 navigation stacks being called from App.js. It seems as soon as i wrap these in `<AuthContext.Provider>` i get the error below. If i remove `<AuthContext.Provider>` the screens work properly without errors.
I have been going though all the documentation i can find on the useContext hook, matching it up to my code, and I cant pinpoint on what I am doing wrong.
Error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function
(for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file 
it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

This error is located at:
    in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import AuthStack from './navigators/AuthStack';
import ProfileStack from './navigators/ProfileStack';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {AuthContext} from './components/AuthenticationContext';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState('');

  const auth = {
    signIn: () => {
      setUserToken('sdf');
      setIsLoading(false);
    },
    signOut: () => {
      setUserToken('');
      setIsLoading(false);
    },
    signUp: () => {
      setUserToken('sdf');
      setIsLoading(false);
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 500);
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.provider value={auth}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {userToken !== '' ? <ProfileStack /> : <AuthStack />}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

AuthenticationContext.js

```
import {createContext} from 'react';

export const AuthContext = createContext();
```

Login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';
import {AuthContext} from '../components/AuthenticationContext';

function Login() {
  const {signIn} = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={require('../assets/images/scrybe_hero_bg.jpg')}
          style={styles.image}>
          <View style={styles.body}>
            <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Welcome To My App</Text>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
              <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={'Email'} />
              <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={'Password'} />
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button title="Sign In" onPress={signIn()} />
                <Button title="Create Account" />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Home.js and Signup.js are relatively the same as Login.js, so i dont think its necessary to include the code for those, but can if it would be helpful. Same goes for AuthStack.js and ProfileStack.js.

TIA

Comment: Possible typo? The auth context looks like it should be a named import in your Login component, i.e. `import { AuthContext } from '../components/AuthenticationContext';`.

Comment: @DrewReese I fixed this typo, i updated all imports of {AuthContext} and the error is still there. WIll update the code to reflect this change.

Comment: What is this syntax: `const App: () => React$Node = () => {`? I've not seen this before and don't see `React$Node` referenced in the code. How do you render `App`? What is at `renderApplication.js:45` in App.js?

Comment: weird right? that was default setup of App.js when i installed it. it works, so i never bothered to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to render `AuthContext.provider` when it should be `AuthContext.Provider` :)